# How can I improve this regex append?

Tags: regex, perl, append

I have this perl command to append a new line and works, but, can it be improved?

```
perl -p -i -e 's/^*.*normal_check_interval*.*5*.*$/\tnormal_check_interval\t\t5\n\tcheck_period\t\t\tmy_time_period/' file.cfg
```

For example I think that I can use something like:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/^*.*normal_check_interval*.*5*.*$/\t$1\n\tcheck_period\t\t\tmy_time_period/' file.cfg
```

but I'm not sure about syntax

thanks in advance

---

EDIT:
@Sobrique suggestion

It is for edit several nagios cfg files at once.

Example:

Before:

```
service{

    ...
    normal_check_interval   5
    ...
}
```

After:

```
service{

    ...
    normal_check_interval   5
    check_period            my_time_period
    ...
}
```

---

Edit 2:

Based in @Borodin answer I finnaly got this:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/^(\s+normal_check_interval\s+5)/$1\n\tcheck_period\t\t\tmy_time_period/' file
```

Comment: Please can you add some sample input/output? It'll make useful answers easier. (E.g. the answer may be something other than a regex pattern replace like that)

Comment: We really need to see the input data

Comment: Is there a reason why my solution didn't work directly? There is really no need to use a subsitution.

Comment: @Borodin your solution worked smoothly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your regex pattern

```
^*.*normal_check_interval*.*5*.*$
```

which starts with `^*` which is *zero or more starts of string* and will raise the warning

> ^* matches null string many times in regex

There is a similar problem with `normal_check_interval*`, which will match `normal_check_interva`, `normal_check_interval`, `normal_check_intervall` etc. I doubt if that is what you wanted. Likewise `5*` will match an empty string, `5`, `55`, `555` etc. so it's pretty much useless

Lets assume you meant

```
^.*normal_check_interval.*5.*$
```

which matches lines containing `normal_check_interval` somewhere, and the digit `5` somewhere later on. That's worryingly non-specific, but rather than a substitution I would just append to the value of `$_` like this

```
perl -i -pe '$_ .= "\tcheck_period\t\t\tmy_time_period\n" if /^\s+normal_check_interval\s+5\b/' file.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters: `*.*` doesn't do what you think it does in a regex.

But that aside - I'd probably do it slightly differently:

```
perl -pe '/normal_check_interval/ && $_ .= "\ncheck_period\tmy_check_period\n"' yourfile
```

Should do the trick - the pattern match will fire when you match the regex, and will append your line to the current line.

Comment: You're adding a superfluous newline. Did you mean `"\tcheck period..."`? and I wouldn't be too sure that the `5` in the OP's pattern is irrelevant!